# How does Ant compile Java source code files?

Tags: ant

Which file and class in Ant source code distribution does this compiling operation?

Does it use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` or `Compiler.compile("")` or something else?

Comment: External compiler is used while running compile tasks. Depending on property values it can be javac or something else(e.g. gcj). You can find more information at: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Comment: How does Ant invoke these compilers (from the Ant java source code) ??

Comment: Look at the Javac class source code that Jayan posted. There is method in which compilation is performed (protected void compile()). You`ll find there references to CompilerAdapter  interface. You can find list of all known implementations of this interfaces at official docs: http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.7.0/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/compilers/CompilerAdapter.html

Comment: Thank you. I finally got to that line: 808 in Execute.java.

It uses Runtime.getRuntime().exec to compile files !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the source code of ant 
[javactask](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javac.java)